# Android ScrollView scrollTo causes another ScrollView onTouch event

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout like:

HorizontalScrollView 1
----RelativeLayout
-------HorizontalScrollView 2

Reason for this, is that `HorizontalScrollView` number 2 handles user touch, and if scrollX is certain, `HorizontalScrollView`1 gets scrollTo called.

This call is causing `HorizontalScrollView` 2 onTouch event called, with translated event X value, which causes flickering when scrolling `HorizontalScrollView`2

Is there some clear solution how to prevent this or some hack?

The output for `HorizontalScrollView`2 touch event x behaves like: 444, 435, 444, 435, 436, 445, 437, 446. And that pops `onScrollChanged` which calls `HorizontalScrollView`1 to scroll and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the flickering away by translating `HorizontalScrollView` 2 onTouch event X position the amount `HorizontalScrollView`1 gets scrolled by it.